# Java zip append line

Tags: java, zip

Is it possible to efficiently append a line into a zip or gzip file?

I'm storing equity market data directly into the file system and I have around 40 different files which are being updated every 5ms.

Whats the best way of doing this?

Comment: Zipfiles don't contain *lines* but files.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid we will not be able to help you since your question lacks detail. What did you try so far, what was the result? Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Updating zip file containing 40 files every 5 milliseconds? I'm so scared

Comment: You can hardly write your data into a file inside a zip file every 5ms -- it will be heavy I/O operations. Also zip file is not designed for this. If you do want to use a zip archive, you should cache your data in memory and write it until the amount reaches a specified number.

Comment: @coolcfan Whats the problem with heavy I/O? Logging does this the whole time.

Comment: Is it even possible to append a line using GZIP? e.g. could you write to a compressed log file without reading the existing file and writing it out?

Comment: As you said, there are 40 files which are being updated every 5 ms. It's not clear for the "update" here. If "update" means writing to disk every 5 ms, then the disk speed will be a bottleneck -- and you want to put the files in a zip file -- the performance may be terrible. You can check this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html and this http://truezip.java.net/ -- via new nio feature in JDK 7, you can mount a zip file as a file system.

Answer (score 1):

Use a database, not a zip file.

Comment: Flat files are recommended way of storing tick data

Answer (score 1):

1. Database is recommended.
2. If you really want to use plain text file, put them directly on the file system (and if you are using Linux, choose a proper file system for it).
3. If you do want to use plain text file and put the text files in a zip file, check zip file system below:

java.nio.file.FileSystems:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html

> The zip file system provider introduced in the Java SE 7 release is an implementation of a custom file system provider. The zip file system provider treats a zip or JAR file as a file system and provides the ability to manipulate the contents of the file. The zip file system provider creates multiple file systems — one file system for each zip or JAR file.

TrueZip
http://truezip.java.net/

> TrueZIP is a Java based plug-in framework for virtual file systems (VFS) which provides transparent access to archive files as if they were just plain directories

**And remember: use memory to cache, reduce disk operations, and make the writing non-blocking.**

Answer (score 0):

Complete cycle of editing zip file (i mean read-modify-close) will produce too much overhead. I think it is better to accumulate changes in memory and modify target file at some reasonable rate (i.e. every 5 seconds or even more).

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be like [compressing data sent over a socket](http://javatechniques.com/blog/compressing-data-sent-over-a-socket/) and flushing compressed blocks to disk from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ZipOutputStream's write method to write at a given offset.

```
String filepath = new String("/tmp/updated.txt")
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/example.zip");
ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(fout);
byte[] file = IOUtils.toByteArray(mWriter.toString());
short yourOffset = 0;

ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(filepath);
try {
    zout.putNextEntry(ze);
    zout.write(file, yourOffset, file.length);
    zout.closeEntry();
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you convert your file to a byte array using Apache commons IOUtils (import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils) you can rewrite and replace the zip entry by calling write at your the offset where the line you want to edit begins. In this case it writes the entire file, from 0 to file.length. You can replace the file in the zip by creating a ZipEntry with a path to the updated file on your drive.